# Base64 gif image is not animated inside <feimage>

Tags: d3.js, svg, filter, animated-gif

I am using filters to display an animated image inside svg:

```
<filter id="filter-id1464674757841" width="100%" height="100%" x="0%"y="0%">
    <feImage xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODl...">
    </feImage>
</filter>
```

The same image works with the `<img/>` tag.

Is there any way to make it work inside `<feimage>` ?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: could you include a [mcve] in the question rather than what you have currently put there?

Comment: I am just asking if it's possible to achieve this using svg filters?

Comment: There's nothing in the SVG specification that suggests that it isn't